# How to filter in nested collections?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Hello StackOverflow community, I am working with laravel and i created this collection

```
$headquarters = collect([
        [
            'headquarter' => 'Leon',
            'offers' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Name1',
                    'slug' => 'Name1'
                ], [
                    'name' => 'Name2',
                    'slug' => 'Name2'
                ]
            ]
        ],[
            'headquarter' => 'Granada',
            'offers' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Name3',
                    'slug' => 'Name3'
                ],[
                    'name' => 'Name4',
                    'slug' => 'Name4'
                ],[
                    'name' => 'Name5',
                    'slug' => 'Name5'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

I want to filter this collection by headquarter and offer slug in order to get a Single offer

Right now i am trying using filter

```
 $offer = $this->headquarters()
        ->filter(function($hq) use ($headquarter, $slug) {
            return $hq['headquarter'] == $headquarter && $hq['offers']['slug'] == $slug;
        });
```

But with no success.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all offers in specific headquarter with this code

```
$this->headquarters()->where('headquarter', 'Leon')[0]['offers'][0];
```

Then for each all offers

```
foreach ($this->headquarters()->where('headquarter', 'Leon')[0]['offers'] as $offer) {
            print_r($offer);
        }
```

or try this code

```
    $offer = collect($this->headquarters()->where('headquarter', $headquarter)
                            ->first()['offers'])
                    ->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed because I need I single offer the <or try this code section> it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

You $hq['offers'] is an array, you should access as $hq['offers'][0]['slug'].

```
 $offer = $this->headquarters()
        ->filter(function($hq) use ($headquarter, $slug) {
            return $hq['headquarter'] == $headquarter && in_array($slug, array_column($hq['offers'], 'slug'));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Kris for the help but in this case I need to get a single offer. If headquarter is Granada and slug is Name3 then the result should be ['name' => 'Name3', 'slug'=>'Name3'].